# How to split a string in java based on a regex?

Tags: java

I have data as follows:

```
String s = "foo.com^null^[]"; 
String s1 = "bar.com^null^[{\"seen_first\":1357882827,\"seen_last\":1357882827,\"_id\":\"93.170.52.31\",\"exclude_from_publication\":false,\"locked\":false,\"agent\":\"domain_export\",\"web_published\":true,\"version\":\"IPv4\"},{\"seen_first\":1357882827,\"seen_last\":1357882827,\"_id\":\"93.170.52.21\",\"exclude_from_publication\":false,\"locked\":false,\"agent\":\"domain_export\",\"web_published\":true,\"version\":\"IPv4\"}]";
```

And note that third field.. it can be either [] or a json array.
And I am trying to parse these fields..

Here is my current attempt.

```
public static void check(String s) {
        String [] tokens = s.split("^");
        System.out.println(tokens[0]);
        System.out.println(tokens[1]);
        System.out.println(tokens[2]);


        if (tokens[2].trim().equals("[]")) {
            System.out.println("here--> " +true);

        }
        System.out.println("---------");


    }
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `^` is special to a regex meaning start of line. Try escaping it: `\\^`.

Comment: How did you end up with such bizarre data? Why not just use JSON on the top level too?

Comment: @squiguy: Duh.. Bingo.. Thanks.. :)

Comment: @ppeterka66 It's not all about rep. I just noticed something right away :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^` is a metacharacter in a regex, meaning "the start of the string". You need to escape it:

```
String [] tokens = s.split("\\^");
```

Comment: I can't believe you made that blunder :)

Comment: @Bohemian: Me neither. It's too late. Off to bed now.